# TinyMCE Text hightlight with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, tinymce

Just asked a question on regular expression here, basically we need to give an option to people to select some part of text which will be hidden with a **MORE** button on flash front end, and when some one will click on **MORE** it will expand it. here is sample text in tinyMCE

```
some text <start> some inner test </end>
```

so here is the regular expression to catch this start and end text,

```
<start>(((?!<(?:\/end|start)>).)+)<\/end>
```

the above expression will be used to strip this SOME INNER TEST and we will convert this to FLASH friendly **MORE** button.

My question is, Is there any way to highlight the text inside start & end tags on the fly (while editing) so people will know which part will be hidden for MORE button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay guys pat my shoulder on this :D If you don't know what are the code below then learn the basic of TinyMCE initializing. I have done this on jQuery version.

Here is my solution

```
var highlighter = 1; // A global variable, just to create a toggle for show/hide highlight
```

added three custom buttons

```
theme_advanced_buttons1: 'startmore, highlight, endmore, ...';
```

add `setup:` to initializing code.

```
// start highlight, end highlight and show highlight buttons

setup: function(ed) {
    ed.addButton('startmore', {
        title: 'Start More',
        image: 'images/end_s.png',
        onclick: function() {
            ed.selection.setContent('[start]');
        }
    });
    ed.addButton('endmore', {
        title: 'End More',
        image: 'images/end_m.png',
        onclick: function() {
            ed.selection.setContent('[end]');
            if (1 == highlighter) {
                highlight_tags();
            }
        }
    });
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
       highlight_tags();
    });
    ed.onSubmit.add(function(ed, e) {
        var html_output = highlight_remove(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(html_output);
    });

    ed.addButton('highlight', {
        title: 'Show collapse selection',
        image: 'images/end_highlight.png',
        onclick: function() {
            if (1 == highlighter) {
                var html_output = highlight_remove(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(html_output);
                highlighter = 0;
            } else {
                highlight_tags();
                highlighter = 1;
            }
        }
    });
    ed.onContextMenu.add(function(ed, e) {
        tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
        if (1 == highlighter) {
            highlight_tags();
        }
    });
}
```

`onContextMenu` is used to show / fix the highlight by right-clicking inside the editor.
There are issue to show highlight on they fly as as soon I `setSontent()` it moves the cursor at the start of first line.

Below are the regular expression functions to put the highlight around the [start][end] tags.

```
function highlight_tags() {
  var html_output = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
  html_output = highlight_remove(html_output);
  var regex = new RegExp(/\[start\](((?!\[(?:end|start)\]).)+)\[end\]/ig);

  html_output = html_output.replace(regex,'<span style="background-color:> yellow;">[start]$1[end]</span>');
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(html_output);
}

function highlight_remove(html_output) {        
  var regex_fix = new RegExp(/<span\sstyle="background-color:\syellow;">(.+?)<\/span>/ig);
  return html_output.replace(regex_fix,'$1');
}
```

Hmm so far it is serving me.

Just `onSubmit` I am trying to remove the highlight so it wont go in database and for a second I can see that highlight is removed. But it goes in database... so fixing this now.

Let me know if you guys didn't understand any part.

NOTE: If there is any typo in code that might be this stack overflow editor :).
NOTE: I know this code can be improved a lot, so enlighten me please.